# IDE gives no errors, but ArrayList fails to work

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, bukkit

I have this in my main class named `RuneCraft` in package `com.mcvigor`:

`public static ArrayList<String> prospPlayers = new ArrayList<String>();`

I have this in another class named `MiningListener` in package `com.mcvigor.listeners`:

```
`   public void playerRClickOre(PlayerInteractEvent event) { //Ore Interactions

    final Player p = event.getPlayer();

    if(event.getPlayer().isOp()) return;

    if(RuneCraft.prospPlayers.contains(p.getName())) return;

    if(isClickedBlockMineral(event) && event.getAction() == Action.LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK && !hasPickaxe(p)) { //block is mineral, player left clicked it, no pickaxe
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You need a pickaxe to mine this."); // ADD CHECKS FOR PICKAXE REQUIRED LEVEL 2 USE
    }

    if(isClickedBlockMineral(event) && event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {

        switch(event.getClickedBlock().getType()) {

        case CLAY: //clay
            RuneCraft.prospPlayers.add(p.getName());
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You examine the rock for ores...");
            Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "This rock contains" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + " clay" + ChatColor.GRAY + ".");
                }
            }, 3*20L); // TODO: Change time
            RuneCraft.prospPlayers.remove(p.getName());
            break;`
```

There's other stuff beneath that, but that is not important. The problem is that when I prospect or examine rocks for ores, its supposed to add me to the list and if I try to do it again, it wont let me until I've finished prospecting (where it removes my name from the ArrayList).

Why is this happening?

Is `if(RuneCraft.prospPlayers.contains(p.getName())) return;` the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
RuneCraft.prospPlayers.add(p.getName());
p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You examine the rock for ores...");
Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "This rock contains" + ChatColor.DARK_RED + " clay" + ChatColor.GRAY + ".");
    }
}, 3*20L); // TODO: Change time
RuneCraft.prospPlayers.remove(p.getName());
```

You're removing the name again *immediately* after you've added it and said that you've started examining it. You only want to remove it *after* you've finished examining it, right? So you need to move the `remove` call to happen when the "later task" executes:

```
RuneCraft.prospPlayers.add(p.getName());
p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "You examine the rock for ores...");
Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(plugin, new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "This rock contains" + 
                      ChatColor.DARK_RED + " clay" + ChatColor.GRAY + ".");
        RuneCraft.prospPlayers.remove(p.getName());
    }
}, 3*20L); // TODO: Change time
```

Admittedly I'd try to avoid using a static variable for this anyway, but that's a different matter.

Comment: Oh wow, what a dumb mistake! Thank you for your answer, I thought it would only execute the code under public void run only after "run" had actually finished. Also, if you don't mind, why would you avoid using a static variable for this?

Comment: @user2510422: Generally speaking, static variables represent global state - not too bad for constants, but *mutable* global state makes it harder to reason about and test your code.